# Kendo Diagram Datasource - json

Tags: json, vb.net, wcf

Goal: Use kendo ui diagram  component to draw a department to project workflow
The workflow is structured in the following manner:
Each Department may have multiple Strategies, each Strategy may have multiple Programs and each Program may have multiple projects.

I have a WCF service that when called returns a json string.
The service calls a stored proc that returns XML, in vb.net then I convert that XML into json (using json.net).

service code:

```
Public Function GetStakeholderRelationshipMatrix(StakeholderId As Integer) As String
    Try
        conn.Open()

        Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter()
        sCommand = New SqlCommand("uspGetRelationshipMatrix", conn)
        sCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StakeholderId", StakeholderId)
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(sCommand.ExecuteScalar())
        Return JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return -1
    End Try
End Function
```

XML Data

```html
<Departments>
  <Department Id="7" Name="Information Technology Department">
    <Strategies Id="21" Name="Increase Revenue">
      <Programs Id="45" Name="Program1">
        <Projects Id="4" Name="test3" />
      </Programs>
      <Programs Id="49" Name="Program4">
        <Projects Id="2" Name="Test1" />
        <Projects Id="3" Name="Test2" />
      </Programs>
    </Strategies>
  </Department>
</Departments>
```

Json Converted Data:

```js
{"d":"{\"Departments\":{\"Department\":{\"@Id\":\"7\",\"@Name\":\"Information Technology Department\",\"Strategies\":{\"@Id\":\"21\",\"@Name\":\"Increase Revenue\",\"Programs\":[{\"@Id\":\"45\",\"@Name\":\"Program1\",\"Projects\":{\"@Id\":\"4\",\"@Name\":\"test3\"}},{\"@Id\":\"49\",\"@Name\":\"Program4\",\"Projects\":[{\"@Id\":\"2\",\"@Name\":\"Test1\"},{\"@Id\":\"3\",\"@Name\":\"Test2\"}]}]}}}}"}
```

I am have been unable to bind the data (json) to the diagram component in order to successfully display the workflow. I need help binding the json string to the diagram component.

Kendo code:

```js
<div id="visual"></div>                   
var dsRelationshipMatrix = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read: function (options) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "wcf service return json string",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    type: "GET",
                                    success: function (result) {
                                        var obj = $.parseJSON(result.d);
                                        if (obj == null) {
                                            options.success([]);
                                        } else {
                                            options.success(obj);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    error: function (result) {
                                        options.error(result)
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        },
                        schema: {
                            data: function (data) {
                                return data
                            }

                        }
                    }); //closes data source
                    function createDiagram() {
                        $("#visual").kendoDiagram({
                            dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                                data: dsRelationshipMatrix,
                                schema: {
                                    model: {
                                        children: "Strategies"
                                    }
                                }
                            }),
                            layout: {
                                type: "layered"
                            },
                            shapeDefaults: {
                                visual: visualTemplate
                            },
                            connectionDefaults: {
                                stroke: {
                                    color: "#979797",
                                    width: 2
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        var diagram = $("#visual").getKendoDiagram();
                        diagram.bringIntoView(diagram.shapes);
                    }
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Could you please specify your question more clearly? Read this [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But I must add you have added alot of information nicely to your question. :)

Comment: I need to be able to setup a hierarchical data source in kendo in order to populate the data in the diagram component. After spending some time researching, I think the problem is that my data has multiple levels in its hierarchy and I am unable to properly setup the hierarchy using the data source hierarchical model in kendo. Departments may have many stratgies and strategies may have many programs and programs may have many projects. So the question is how do I setup a hierarchical data source within in kendo to support the structured mentioned. I am open to using json or xml for data.

Comment: By the way, I apologize for not being direct when I first posted the "question"

Answer (score 0):

After going through the pain for some time, I got it to work and wanted to share that information with everyone. This might not be the perfect way but it is one of the ways to do it.
The key is going to be the structure of the SQL data (extracted as XML).

In SQL I ended up performing a recursive loop that extracts the data and formats it into XML. So a root node of ROOT encompasses an item (Department - there can only be one department) and each hierarchical category has an items section with an item section as a child of items. Wording the structure is rather difficult so...

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    --dStakeholder.StakeholderId AS '@Id', 
    dStakeholder.FunctionalDepartment as 'item/info' ,
    '#1696d3' as 'item/colorScheme',
    (SELECT 
        --dStrategy.StrategyId AS '@Id', 
        dStrategy.StrategyDescription 'item/info',
        '#1696d3' as 'item/colorScheme' ,
        (Select
            --dPrograms.ProgramId as '@Id',
            dPrograms.ProgramDescription 'item/info' ,
            '#1696d3' as 'item/colorScheme' ,
            (Select
                --dHeaders.ProjectId as '@Id',
                dHeaders.ProjectName  'item/info',
                '#1696d3' as 'item/colorScheme'
                    from
                    dbo.ProjectHeaders as dHeaders
                        inner join (select distinct projectid, programid, departmentid from dbo.ProjectHeaders) as pp
                            on dHeaders.ProjectId = pp.ProjectId
                        where pp.ProgramId = dPrograms.ProgramId and pp.departmentid = dStakeholder.Stakeholderid
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ) as 'item/items'
            from
            dbo.ProjectPrograms as dPrograms
            inner join (select distinct programid, strategyid , departmentid from dbo.ProjectHeaders) as sp
                on dPrograms.ProgramId = sp.ProgramId
            where sp.StrategyId = dStrategy.StrategyId and sp.departmentid = dstakeholder.stakeholderid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) as 'item/items'
     FROM 
        dbo.ProjectStrategies as dStrategy
        inner join (select distinct strategyid , departmentid from dbo.ProjectHeaders) as bss
            on dStrategy.StrategyId = bss.StrategyId
     WHERE 
         dStakeholder.StakeholderId = bss.DepartmentId 
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) as 'item/items'
FROM 
    dbo.Stakeholders as dStakeholder
FOR XML PATH('root'), type
```

My data from the sql appears in XML in this manner:

```html
<root>
  <item>
    <info>ERISA Compliance Services Department</info>
    <colorScheme>#1696d3</colorScheme>
    <items>
      <item>
        <info>New Commission</info>
        <colorScheme>#1696d3</colorScheme>
        <items>
          <item>
            <info>Program3</info>
            <colorScheme>#1696d3</colorScheme>
            <items>
              <item>
                <info>test3</info>
                <colorScheme>#1696d3</colorScheme>
              </item>
            </items>
          </item>
        </items>
      </item>
      <item>
        <info>SAGA Development</info>
        <colorScheme>#1696d3</colorScheme>
        <items>
          <item>
            <info>Program1</info>
            <colorScheme>#1696d3</colorScheme>
            <items>
              <item>
                <info>Test1</info>
                <colorScheme>#1696d3</colorScheme>
              </item>
            </items>
          </item>
          <item>
            <info>Program4</info>
            <colorScheme>#1696d3</colorScheme>
            <items>
              <item>
                <info>Test2</info>
                <colorScheme>#1696d3</colorScheme>
              </item>
            </items>
          </item>
        </items>
      </item>
    </items>
  </item>
</root>
```

Now I go through my xml and grab the important information. Code in VB.net. There is a class for item that just list the properties that I would need.

```
            conn.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("uspGetRelationshipMatrix " + Convert.ToString(StakeholderId), conn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
        If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                sb.Append(row.Item("Data"))
            Next
        End If
        conn.Close()


        xmlDoc.LoadXml(sb.ToString)

        Dim itemList As New List(Of Item)
        Dim RootNode As XmlNode
        RootNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root")

        For Each DeptNode As XmlNode In RootNode.ChildNodes
            Dim deptItem As New Item
            'check to ensure that is not nothing
            Dim info As XmlNode = DeptNode.SelectSingleNode("info")
            Dim cs As XmlNode = DeptNode.SelectSingleNode("colorScheme")
            deptItem.info = info.InnerText
            deptItem.colorScheme = cs.InnerText
            'Begin items loop for child nodes
            Dim stratItems As XmlNode = DeptNode.SelectSingleNode("items")
            For Each stratItemNode As XmlNode In stratItems.ChildNodes
                Dim stratItem As New Item
                Dim stratinfo As XmlNode = stratItemNode.SelectSingleNode("info")
                Dim stratcs As XmlNode = stratItemNode.SelectSingleNode("colorScheme")
                stratItem.info = stratinfo.InnerText
                stratItem.colorScheme = stratcs.InnerText
                'place start loop
                Dim progItems As XmlNode = stratItemNode.SelectSingleNode("items")
                For Each progItemNode As XmlNode In progItems.ChildNodes
                    Dim progItem As New Item
                    Dim proginfo As XmlNode = progItemNode.SelectSingleNode("info")
                    Dim progcs As XmlNode = progItemNode.SelectSingleNode("colorScheme")
                    progItem.info = proginfo.InnerText
                    progItem.colorScheme = progcs.InnerText
                    'place start loop
                    Dim projItems As XmlNode = progItemNode.SelectSingleNode("items")
                    For Each projItemNode As XmlNode In projItems.ChildNodes
                        Dim projItem As New Item
                        Dim projinfo As XmlNode = projItemNode.SelectSingleNode("info")
                        Dim projcs As XmlNode = projItemNode.SelectSingleNode("colorScheme")
                        projItem.info = projinfo.InnerText
                        projItem.colorScheme = projcs.InnerText
                        'place start loop
                        'place end loop
                        progItem.items.Add(projItem)
                    Next
                    'place end loop
                    stratItem.items.Add(progItem)
                Next
                'place end loop
                deptItem.items.Add(stratItem)
            Next
            'end items loop
            itemList.Add(deptItem)
        Next
```

I then use newtonsoft json in vb.net in order to present the information as a json string.
Json string:

```
[ 
```

{  
      "info":"ERISA Compliance Services Department",
      "colorScheme":"#1696d3",
      "items":[  
         {  
            "info":"New Commission",
            "colorScheme":"#1696d3",
            "items":[  
               {  
                  "info":"Program3",
                  "colorScheme":"#1696d3",
                  "items":[  
                     {  
                        "info":"test3",
                        "colorScheme":"#1696d3",
                        "items":[ 

```
                    ]
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "info":"SAGA Development",
        "colorScheme":"#1696d3",
        "items":[  
           {  
              "info":"Program1",
              "colorScheme":"#1696d3",
              "items":[  
                 {  
                    "info":"Test1",
                    "colorScheme":"#1696d3",
                    "items":[  

                    ]
                 }
              ]
           },
           {  
              "info":"Program4",
              "colorScheme":"#1696d3",
              "items":[  
                 {  
                    "info":"Test2",
                    "colorScheme":"#1696d3",
                    "items":[  

                    ]
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
```

}
]

With the json formatted in this structure, now I just plugged my json to kendo diagram and now you get a visual hierarchical image of flow.